# How can I remove the tab "Subusers" in the profile?

Tags: 7, routes

I have installed the module subusers and appears a tab named "Subusers" in the profile.  How can I remove this tab?

I tested this code in template.tpl.php and I didn't work:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

$unwanted_tabs = array('user/%/subuser');
  foreach ($variables['tabs'] as $group_key => $tab_group) {
    if (is_array($tab_group)) {
      foreach ($tab_group as $key => $tab) {
        if (isset($tab['#link']['path']) && in_array($tab['#link']['path'], $unwanted_tabs)){
          unset($variables['tabs'][$group_key][$key]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried with this code:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
    unset($items['user/%/subuser']);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [tabtamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module provides an easy way to remove tabs, both those generated by core as well as those generated by modules.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I faced but I used patch for it which is still needs review but its work form me [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1483590) because Tabtamer hides tab from every user.
So I downloaded the patch file in sites/all/modules/contrib/subuser

```
wget https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/subuser-remove-tab-if-no-permissions-148590-11.patch
```

and then applied patch with following command.

```
git apply -v subuser-remove-tab-if-no-permissions-148590-11.patch
```